# Intent not carrying data to next activity, and button to go back to previous activity not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have this code here that basically produces a number guessing game.  Once three tries have been expired, it takes you to the Game Over screen, and should display your score.  On the Game Over screen you can click the Try Again button, but it is not following the intent to open the MainActivity again.  Any pointers?

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int n = 0;
Random random = new Random();
static int score = 0;
int m = random.nextInt(9 - 1) + 1;
int tries = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public static String scoreFinal = "scoreFinal";

public void arg(){
    if (tries < 1){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOver.class);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreFinalText);
        intent.putExtra(scoreFinal, score);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
    if (n == m) {
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        text.setText("You are correct! I've come up with a new number, can you guess it?.");
        score += 1;
        tries = 3;
        m = random.nextInt(9 - 1) + 1;
    } else if (n < m){
        tries -= 1;
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        text.setText("You are incorrect. This number is lower then mine.");
    } else if (n > m){
        tries -= 1;
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        text.setText("You are incorrect. This number is higher then mine.");
    }
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreNum);
    String i = Integer.toString(score);
    text.setText(i);

    TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.triesNum);
    String j = Integer.toString(tries);
    text2.setText(j);
    }
}
public void send1(View view) {
    n = 1;
    arg();

}
public void send2(View view) {
    n = 2;
    arg();
}
public void send3(View view) {
    n = 3;
    arg();

}
public void send4(View view) {
    n = 4;
    arg();

}
public void send5(View view) {
    n = 5;
    arg();

}
public void send6(View view) {
    n = 6;
    arg();

}
public void send7(View view) {
    n = 7;
    arg();

}
public void send8(View view) {
    n = 8;
    arg();

}
public void send9(View view) {
    n = 1;
    arg();

}
```

}

Game Over Screen:

```
public class GameOver extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String scoreFinal = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.scoreFinal);

    // Create the text view
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreFinalText);
    text.setText(scoreFinal);
}


public void tryAgainButton(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
```

}

Game Over Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gameOver"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:text="Game Over!"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scoreFinalText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scoreInfo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scoreInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gameOver"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gameOver"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="Your score was:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tryAgainButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scoreInfo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scoreFinalText"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:text="Try Again?" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There is no clicklistener here !

Comment: can you put your GameOver layout over here? Have you even connected the tryAgainButton method to the correct Button?

Comment: Added the GameOver layout~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tgrll mentioned in a comment, you have to add the method `tryAgainButton` as onClickListener in your layout otherwise nothing happens if you don't add the onclick method programmatically:

**android:onClick="tryAgainButton"**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/tryAgainButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scoreInfo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scoreFinalText"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:text="Try Again?" 
    android:onClick="tryAgainButton" />
```

Comment: I completely missed that step there, now it switches back to the reset activity just fine.  However, I'm still clueless as to why the intent value is not being carried over properly

Comment: Try `int scoreFinal = intent.getExtras().getInt("scoreFinal");`